# How To Build A Custom Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to build a `Regex` which begins with 5 or 6 integers and ends with a character.

I have tried

```
^\d+A-Za-z$
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this: 
You should look into some regex rules, and see other examples on SO.

```
^\d{5,6}[A-Za-z]$
```

The main difference is that you need to encapsulate the last rule in [], so it means, one character, either a-z or A-Z. And you need to replace `\d+` with `\d{5,6}`.

`\d+` means: a digit, at least once.

`\d{x,y}`: a digit, minimum x times, maximum y times.

Answer (score 0):

You were quite close.  Few minor modifications.

`^\d{5,6}[A-Za-z]$`

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you mean a-z (case insensitive) as "characters" `\d{5,6}[a-zA-z]$`

This is quite simple though - check out this site for a decent introduction: http://www.regular-expressions.info/